# Windows Form Application won't initialize

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to write a windows application to do some file reading, manipulation and writing in C# and I'm mostly done except that when I run my code it wont open up my app but instead brings me to a blank terminal screen.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public string fPath;
    public string nfName;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fPath = textBox1.Text;
        nfName = textBox2.Text;
    }

    public string getPath()
    {
        return fPath;
    }

    public string getFileName()
    {
        return nfName;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code for for the app itself. ^^^

```
static void Main()
{
    Form1 f = new Form1();
    string path = f.getPath();
    string nFileName = f.getFileName();

}
```

This is the code for the beginning of my `main`. ^^^

I have these two sections in different classes and in the same namespace.  I want for this `main` to be the entry point and then for it to call my form and initialize it so that I can input my file path and process it but despite creating an instance of the Form1 class, it will not initialize. I have tried `f.Form1()` but it will not recognize that as a method of my object for whatever reason.

Comment: Did you by any chance create a console application project and then add a WinForm to it?

Answer (score 4):

In your main method you should start the UI message loop. `Application.Run` does that for you. Also, it will show the form for you and keeps the application running meanwhile.

```
Form1 f = new Form1();
...
Application.Run(f);
```

Comment: @user3712526: Need more help? If not, please don't forget to mark your question answered by checking the checkmark before the question you liked most.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `Application.Run`

Here's what the standard Main() looks like for WinForms

```
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, you need to call `Application.Run(f)`, but if you are seeing a command window, you may need to change your output type in your project settings:

[image]